# I cannot see my uploaded image in stackoverflow

Tags: support, images, imgur

This is the topic that I posted [How to refresh or show immediately in datagridview after inserting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299016/how-to-refresh-or-show-immediately-in-datagridview-after-inserting). I uploaded a image, but it didn't display. Is it the website problem?

Comment: Something on your end is blocking the domain http://imgur.com. Many companies block it and it's black listed on many places because it hosts NSFW pictures as well. So, if you browse from your workplace or use VPN to your workplace it explains the problem. Otherwise, contact your ISP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image is there. I think it took a while to load the image.

Comment: ok @Tom Doyle I still dun see it tho

Comment: Is http://i.stack.imgur.com/PbdjQ.jpg the image you're aiming for?

Comment: What? I click your link, and it says Oops! Google Chrome could not find i.stack.imgur.com

Comment: It's a problem on your end.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you get a 502 Proxy error.

If you use Chrome, you can take a look at the Console output. For example, I don't get to see the image either, but Chrome tells me

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502
>   (Proxy Error ( Company denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator
>   (URL). ))

Comment: I see. omg i use firefox, the image also doesn;t appear. @ChrisLava